# Animation does not appear over parent background

Tags: css, animation

I am attempting to animate 3 circles in a line.

The start and end circle are shown without issue, but the 'center' circle has a white background, I assume from the parent div.

I would like for the center circle to have the same background as the others. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

```css
@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 -0.8em, 0 0 0 -0.8em, 28px 0 0 -0.8em;
  }

  12.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 0, 0 0 0 -0.8em, 28px 0 0 -0.8em;
  }

  25% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 0.2em, 0 0 0 0, 28px 0 0 -0.8em;
  }

  37.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 0, 0 0 0 0.2em, 28px 0 0 0;
  }

  50% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 -0.2em, 0 0 0 0, 28px 0 0 0.2em;
  }

  62.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 -0.4em, 0 0 0 -0.2em, 28px 0 0 0;
  }

  75% {
    box-shadow: -28px 0 0 -0.6em, 0 0 0 -0.4em, 28px 0 0 -0.2em;
  }
}

#app {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#spinner {
  border-radius: 9999px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite linear;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a working example here using the question's editor, if the link is no longer reachable the question becomes useless

Comment: @Sfili_81 Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of the element itself is always cut out from the `box-shadow`. That's why `background: transparent` doesn't work either. `background: #000` doesn't work either, because then the middle circle cannot become smaller than 7x7px.

What you can do, however, is apply an offset on the y axis (I used +10px) and then shift the whole element back (in this case -10px) using `transform: translateY()`:

```css
@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 -0.8em, 0 10px 0 -0.8em, 28px 0 10px -0.8em;
  }

  12.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 0, 0 10px 0 -0.8em, 28px 0 10px -0.8em;
  }

  25% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 0.2em, 0 10px 0 0, 28px 10px 0 -0.8em;
  }

  37.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 0, 0 10px 0 0.2em, 28px 10px 0 0;
  }

  50% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 -0.2em, 0 10px 0 0, 28px 10px 0 0.2em;
  }

  62.5% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 -0.4em, 0 10px 0 -0.2em, 28px 10px 0 0;
  }

  75% {
    box-shadow: -28px 10px 0 -0.6em, 0 10px 0 -0.4em, 28px 10px 0 -0.2em;
  }
}

#app {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#spinner {
  border-radius: 9999px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite linear;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can adjust the speed however you see fit.

```css
.spinner,
.spinner:before,
.spinner:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: animate 2s infinite linear;
  animation: animate 2s infinite linear;
}
.spinner {
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.spinner:before,
.spinner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.spinner:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.spinner:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```